# How to check if a tuple contains an element in Python?

Tags: python, collections, tuples

I tried to find the available methods but couldn't find it. There is no `contains`. Should I use `index`? I just want to know if the item exists, don't need the index of it.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You use `in`.

```
if element in thetuple:
    #whatever you want to do.
```

Comment: Thanks, for multiple elements should I do if a in tuple and b in tuple: ?

Comment: Yes. If you have a lot of elements you might consider using `set`s instead, where you can do union, difference and intersection operations.

Comment: Thanks, actually the API I am using is returning a tuple, that's why I was using that. Should I convert it to a set?

Comment: @JoanVenge: If you want it to be a set, yes.

Comment: Thanks will do. I just didn't want to change the data types too much because it's gonna get called 10000s of times every frame.

Comment: @JoanVenge: Yes, making a `set` of a `tuple` is a heavy operation, so doing that 10.0000 times is generally not desirable. You have a specific situation and a specific problem, but you ask very generic questions. The answers you get will not be very useful.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will just use `in` twice because it's only 2 checks. I just didn't want to make it very messy.

Comment: Then using a set is not useful.

Answer (score 10):

```
if "word" in str(tuple):
# You can convert the tuple to str too
```

i has the same problem and only worked to me after the convert str()

Comment: Hi new contributor. Your answer was similar as accepted answer, but you should know that keyword **in** is same as `__contains__` overloaded operator on class. So when original poster said that there was no `__contains__`  he/she meant that it wasn't possible to use **in** keyword on data set. As you can see string class has that operator implemented so your answer is ok. Keep going! :D

Comment: its true, i was not seen the specification in the question. I was looking to solve my problem (a 'str' situation) and I found that the question wasnt about it only after the answer haha

Comment: That's not good solution, since it will return true even if the tuple contains "sword".

Comment: Good solution indeed. Lennart Regebro's solution doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with that:
return Oops.
use Set: d= {...}

```
def simha():
    d = ('this_is_valid')
    b = 'valid'
    if b in d:
        print("Oops!!!!!")


simha()
```

Comment: tuples are only created in python if you use the notation ```(element,)```. The comma is very important. If there is no comma, python treats it like an expression to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows: `variable_name in tuple`

```py
animals = ('Dog', 'Elephant', 'Fox')

animal_name = 'Fox'
```

Check if an x is in `animals` tuple:

```py
if animal_name in animals :
    # Fox is existing in animals
```

Check if an x is NOT in `animals` tuple:

```py
if not animal_name in animals :
    # Fox is not existing in animals
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
fruits = ['peach', 'blueberry', 'raspberry', 'apple', 'orange',  'lemon', 'banana']
first, second, *others = fruits

print(others) # ['raspberry', 'apple', 'orange', 'lemon', 'banana']
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense with the question...