# Loop though all rows of tuple and return a value once a condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x

This toy example kind of represents a problem I have parsing data from a simulation package. I want to loop through a tuple and if a particular condition is met break the loop and return the time step that corresponds with that particular row. In the following example index 0 represents these time steps.

```
from random import randint

t = list(range(1,11))
a = [randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 10)]
b = [randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 10)]
c = [randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 10)]
d = [randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 10)]
e = [randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 10)]

for i in zip(t,a,b,c,d,e):
    print (i)

(1, 8, 5, 5, 3, 4)
(2, 2, 9, 5, 9, 1)
(3, 9, 3, 1, 6, 3)
(4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 3)
(5, 2, 7, 6, 8, 10)
(6, 6, 6, 8, 9, 6)
(7, 1, 8, 1, 8, 3)
(8, 1, 1, 1, 7, 5)
(9, 6, 10, 7, 4, 6)
(10, 5, 2, 6, 3, 8)
```

So lets say I want to return the first time step that the number 10 appears. Knowing that that is time step 5 and 10 is the last in the row I could hard code this:

```
for i in zip(t,a,b,c,d,e):
    if i[5] == 10:
        print(i[0])
5
```

I tried to solve the problem this way but I cant quite work out where I am going wrong, any pointers would be welcome.

```
for i in zip(t,a,b,c,d,e):
    if i[1:] == 10:
        print(i[0])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a tuple contains an element in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920147/how-to-check-if-a-tuple-contains-an-element-in-python)

Comment: `if 10 in i:print(i[0]);break`

Comment: Thanks pranav, not quite. The order is important which is why I am using a loop. Ie 10 could appear further down row wise but I only care about the first instance of it since this is actually a time series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like everyone else, add a `break` statement in your `if` statement. That'll get you out of the loop.

```py
for i in zip(t, a, b, c, d, e):
    if 10 in i[1:]:
        print(i[0])
        break
```

But, as a bonus, you can add an `else` statement at the bottom of your for loop if you want to know if 10 was never in `i[1:]` like so:

```
for i in zip(t, a, b, c, d, e):
    if 10 in i[1:]:
        print(i[0])
        break
else:  # If the loop never exited abnormally
    print("10 was never in i[1:]")
```

To learn more about the `for/else` syntax, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops?noredirect=1&lq=1) StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach

```
 from random import randint
    
    t = list(range(1,11))
    a = [randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 10)]
    b = [randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 10)]
    c = [randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 10)]
    d = [randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 10)]
    e = [randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 10)]
    
    for i in zip(t,a,b,c,d,e):
        print (i)
    
    for lst in zip(t,a,b,c,d,e):
        if 10 in lst:
            print(lst[0])
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
for i in zip(t,a,b,c,d,e):
    if i[1:] == 10:
        print(i[0])
```

with

```
for i in zip(t,a,b,c,d,e):
    if 10 in i:
        print(i[0])
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `random.seed()`, to make examples reproducible ([tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_seed.asp)).

From there, as you did:

```
from random import randint
import random

random.seed(42)
ten_numbers = range(0, 10)
t = list(range(1,11))
a = [randint(1, 10) for i in ten_numbers]
b = [randint(1, 10) for i in ten_numbers]
c = [randint(1, 10) for i in ten_numbers]
d = [randint(1, 10) for i in ten_numbers]
e = [randint(1, 10) for i in ten_numbers]
```

Can continue with:

```
for index, each in enumerate(zip(t,a,b,c,d,e)):
    if any([EACH == 10 for EACH in each]):
        print(index)
        break
else:
    print("10 couldn't be found")
```

Where we used a [for-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops) clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `break` call in order to stop a loop once a condition is met.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
target = 5
time_step = 0

for time_step, value in enumerate(list):
    if value == target:
        break
```

If you are dealing with multiple lists, I would suggest checking which list has the value you are searching for, and then extracting its index.

```
lists = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]

target = 5 
time_step = 0

for list in lists:
    if target in list:
        for time_step, value in enumerate(list):
            if value == target:
                break
```